# Oracle SQL Sub-Query how to use result from query A to restrict query B

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

Goal:

- Combine two queries I currently run.
- Have the WEEK from query 1 be a filtering criteria for query 2.

**Query 1:**

```
----------------------------------------------------
-- ************************************************
-- Accounts Recieveable (WEEKLY) snapshot
-- ************************************************
----------------------------------------------------
SELECT 
    TRUNC(TX.ORIG_POST_DATE,'WW') AS WEEK, 
    SUM(TX.AMOUNT) AS OUTSTANDING
FROM 
    TX
WHERE
    --Transaction types
    (TX.DETAIL_TYPE = "Charges" OR 
    TX.DETAIL_TYPE = "Payments" OR 
    TX.DETAIL_TYPE = "Adjustments") 
GROUP BY
    TRUNC(tx.ORIG_POST_DATE,'WW')
ORDER BY
    TRUNC(tx.ORIG_POST_DATE,'WW')
```

**Output Query 1:**

```
    WEEK    OUTSTANDING
1/1/2012    18203.95
1/8/2012    17605
1/15/2012   19402.33
1/22/2012   18693.45
1/29/2012   19100
```

**Query 2:**

```
----------------------------------------------------
-- ************************************************
-- Weekly Charge AVG over previous 13 weeks based on WEEK above
-- ************************************************
----------------------------------------------------

SELECT 
    sum(tx.AMOUNT)/91
FROM 
    TX
WHERE
    --Post date
    TX.ORIG_POST_DATE <= WEEK AND
    TX.ORIG_POST_DATE >= WEEK-91 AND
    --Charges
    (TX.DETAIL_TYPE = "Charge")
```

**Output Query 2:**

```
thirteen_Week_Avg
1890.15626
```

**Desired Output**

```
WEEK        OUTSTANDING Thirteen_Week_Avg
1/1/2012    18203.95    1890.15626
1/8/2012    17605       1900.15626
1/15/2012   19402.33    1888.65132
1/22/2012   18693.45    1905.654
1/29/2012   19100       1900.564
```

Note the Thirteen_Week_Avg is 13 weeks prior to the "WEEK" Field. So it changes each week as the window of the average moves forward.

Also what tutorials do you guys know of that I could read to better understand the solution this type of question?

Comment: Check out the WITH clause:  http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_with_clause.htm

Comment: If you have a question similar to mine above I highly encourage you to check out this overview of Oracle Analytic functions that can be found on youtube at sheepsqueezers channel, http://www.youtube.com/user/sheepsqueezersYT/search?query=analytic,  or http://www.sheepsqueezers.com/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using an analytic function such as:

```
  select WEEK, sum(OUTSTANDING) as OUTSTANDING, THIRTEEN_WEEK_AVG
    from (select trunc(TX.ORIG_POST_DATE, 'WW') as WEEK
                ,AMOUNT as OUTSTANDING
                ,avg(
                   TX.AMOUNT)
                 over (order by trunc(TX.ORIG_POST_DATE, 'WW')
                       range numtodsinterval(7 * 13, 'day') preceding)
                   as THIRTEEN_WEEK_AVG
            from TX
           where (TX.DETAIL_TYPE = 'Charges'
                  or TX.DETAIL_TYPE = 'Payments'
                  or TX.DETAIL_TYPE = 'Adjustments'))
group by WEEK, THIRTEEN_WEEK_AVG
order by WEEK
```

An introduction to analytic functions can be found [here](http://orafaq.com/node/55). And how `NUMTODSINTERVAL` works is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions117.htm#i88258).

Comment: So after implementing your solution it is listing each transaction that happens. So I have multiple days repeating with the same average for that day. I've tried to throw the Group By trunc(TX.ORIG_POST_DATE,'ww') but get an error that it is not a group by expression.

Comment: I've updated the code to wrap a `select` around it to allow grouping.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is this is best handled by a stored procedure that sets two cursors, one for each of the queries and each cursor takes in a week parameter.  You could call the first cursor that outputs the week and outstanding and have this loop through however many times and move back 1 week each time through.  then pass that week to the thirteen week avg cursor and let it output the avg amount.

If you just want it on the screen you can use dbms_output.put_line.   If you want to write it to a file such as a csv then you need to set a filehandler and all the associated plumbing to create/open/write/save a file.

O'reilly  has a pretty good pl/sql book that explains procs and cursors well.